# Calculating the Hilbert Function of a Complete Intersection

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, hilbert-polynomial

I've hear that the Hilbert function is easy to calculate for complete intersections, but I haven't been able to find material that adequately explains why that is. More specifically, any information on calculating the multiple powers of the difference operator of the Hilbert function for a complete intersection is appreciated. I have tried to compute the Hilbert function by putting the complete intersection in an exact sequence but I am having trouble getting it to work.

Thanks

Comment: To be clear, are you having trouble with understanding the conceptual argument about why the Hilbert polynomial is easy to compute or going from the conclusions of that argument to actually producing a polynomial given a complete intersection?

Comment: Both I suppose. My general understanding is that the koszul complex of a complete intersection is a minimal free resolution, and that the hilbert function can be easily computed from a finite free resolution, thus it is easily computed for a complete intersection. I'm having some trouble finding sources that cover this though, primarily a definition of complete intersection that isn't strictly category theoretic or geometric.